# Python how to read cropped Word with CV2 and convert to gray?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to make letter segmentation and I'm using WordDetector to crop words as this code

```
def contours_words(image_file):
    im3 = image_file.copy()
    img = prepare_img(image_file, 50)
    detections = detect(img,
                        kernel_size=25,
                        sigma=3,
                        theta=8,
                        min_area=100)

    line = sort_line(detections)[0]

    for i, word in enumerate(line):
        if word.bbox.h > 19 and word.bbox.w >= 22 and word.bbox.w <= 250:
            contours_letters(word.img)
```

I got an array cropped Image so I need to read it with OpenCV to convert it to grayscale and
use it to make find contour like that

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image_file, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
dilated = cv2.dilate(thresh1, None, iterations=1)

cnts = cv2.findContours(
    dilated.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
cnts = sort_contours(cnts, method="left-to-right")[0]
```

when I try to read the array image with

```
image = cv2.imread(image_file)
```

I got an error and I don't need to save the image and re-read it again to not save images at the client thanks all

Comment: "got an error" -- then it might be a good idea to tell us what it was. Python doesn't print out all that information just for fun, it's quite relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer I need to convert it to RGB color image then I convert it to gray scale

```
opencvImage = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(image_file), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(opencvImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense -- if the source is RGB rather than BGR, just use `COLOR_RGB2GRAY` instead of `COLOR_BGR2GRAY`. What might make difference is the conversion of `image_file` to `np.array` -- however since you did not provide a proper [mcve] let alone the actual error message you get, it's all just guessing.

Comment: @DanMašek because I need to make contour at the image so I need to convert the image to grayscale and I'm using another function splitting the image cropped to array not cv2 shape

Comment: Sure, but you certainly don't need two separate calls to `ctvColor` to achieve that conversion, so that's not the solution. As I said, edit your question, add a [mcve] that reproduces the problem, including the complete text of the error message you get.